# FBJS...OnClick not being passed. DHTML/setInnerXHtml problem

Tags: dhtml, fbjs

thanks so much in advance...here is the problem...

I am trying to add dynamic HTML  element (EX. [delete]),everytime on a event call using FBJS.I am able to append the element using following code.

var oldFriendHtml = document.getElementById('friend_container');
var numi =  document.getElementById('theValue');
var num = (document.getElementById("theValue").getValue()-1)+2;
numi.value = num;
var newElementId = "new"+num;
var newFriendHTML = document.createElement('div');
newFriendHTML.setId(newElementId);
newFriendHTML.setInnerXTML("HTML TO BE ADDED");
oldFriendHtml.appendChild(newFriendHTML);

The problem  I am facing is that FBJS parses out the onClick part (event call ) out from the original HTML added .This stops me in the further activity on the added element .It also removes the  styling added in the HTML    ..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding onclick being parsed out of setInnerXHTML, you can add the event later by using addEventListener.

Here is some sample:

```
var my_obj = document.getElementById('test');
// add a new event listener for each type of event you needed to capture
my_obj.addEventListener('click',my_click_func); // in your case is onclick

function my_click_func(evnt){
   // some action
}
```

more details see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs#events