# how to dynamically populate a drop down box in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, fbjs

I have a problem here : I want to dynamically populate a drop down box based on the selection of another drop down box !

in the main drop down box, I have an onchange= some_JS_function() that gets the data from my sql server. if I want to have the whole drop down html code and put it using setInnerXHTML(), then the  part of the code received from my server is removed in the new drop down box. apart from that everything else is ok !

i tried to just have the options come in and put them at the appropriate places. however, this is not working at all.

can anyone please help me ?

thanks

-
ahsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what I need :         [FBJS...OnClick not being passed. DHTML/setInnerXHtml problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640290/fbjs-onclick-not-being-passed-dhtml-setinnerxhtml-problem)

thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need:

http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Or if you want to do it with JS only:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function ReplaceContentInContainer(id) {
    var content;
    switch(id)
    {
        case "1":
        content = '<option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option>';
        break;

        case "2":
        content = '<option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option>';
        break;

        case "3":
        content = '<option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option>';
        break;

        default:
        content = '<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = content;
    }
    //-->
</script>

<select name="test" id="test" onChange="ReplaceContentInContainer(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select name="second" id="second"></select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well, I  can do it...doing it is not the problem..the problem is the <onchange=some_js_function()> part goes missing. Are you sure, jquery works with facebook ?

Comment: ok, so jquery works with facebook. http://userscripts.org/topics/23292?page=1#posts-103426  however, this is a very trivial problem and I was kind of hoping to solve it without using jquery :(

Comment: Check above. This should work for you, even though I would suggest using jQuery, since it is simpler, and better.

Comment: thanks for the help...maybe I was unable to fully explain my situation. the options are gonna be dynamic !..the following answer link works nicely for me, thanks again ! :)